# Get vmxnet3 working on Solaris 11 Express and Vmware ESX 4.0

Tags: solaris, vmware-esx, vmware-tools

I've installed Solaris 11 express VM and installed tools over it. ESX reports VMware Tools: OK but I can't see vmxnet3 adapter in "ifconfig -a".

Ideas?

Comment: ipconfig isn't a Solaris command. I guess you mean ifconfig.

Comment: I'm sorry. For sure ifconfig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What says

```
ifconfig -a plumb
ifconfig -a
```

?

Comment: yepp. After plumb it's working

Answer (score 0):

Even if the `/etc/hosts`, `nodename` and `netmasks` files are populated, these steps have to be done.

To configure a static IP:

```
ipadm create-ip <LINK>
ipadm create-addr -T static -a local=<IP>/24 <LINK>/v4static
```

To configure using DHCP:

```
ipadm create-ip <LINK>
ipadm create-addr -T dhcp <LINK>/v4
```

`/etc/defaultrouter` is deprecated so use:

```
route -p add default ip-address
```